# WM-API: aнализ примечания платежа

Tags: webmoney, api, php

Всем привет!

***Как произвести анализ примечания платежа?***

Пример:

1. На webmoney кошелек пришел платеж с примечанием "ЗА ТОВАР-1" на сумму 100 рублей.
2. На этот же кошелек пришел платеж с примечанием "ЗА ТОВАР-2" на сумму 50 рублей.
3. На этот же кошелек пришел платеж с примечанием "ЗА ТОВАР-1" на сумму 150 рублей.

Нужно получить такую информацию:

Примечание, количество платежей, Сумма

"ЗА ТОВАР-1", 2, 250 рублей 
"ЗА ТОВАР-2", 1, 50 рублей

**Спасибо за ответы.**